# We're going to need a distinct look / theme

Tags: discussion

Almost other successful Stack Exchange web sites have their unique color themes, logos an so on. Some of them have chosen (or simply not considered to do otherwise) to stay with the default one, meaning the one we have right now.

How do we change our look and what kind of look do we want?

Comment: All sites when they are launched have a theme designed for them. Sites in beta remain with the default theme until they are ready or nearly ready to be launched full time. Only Jin, the designer, can change the theme. But it's still a good idea to thing about it now.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that.

Comment: Yeah, I agree thinking about it now will really help things along.

Comment: Someone please make this a wiki.

Comment: @Phonon - First, why is wiki status necessary for this question?  ([It's probably not necessary](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/)). Second, current users can't make this change, it must be done by a mod - So flag it as "Other - This should be CW because ..." to get it changed.

Answer (score 1):

One idea that I have regards the division bar/dividers/title bar ... a left to right transition:

static -> something digital (a little binary matrix)  -> sinusoidal waves -> representations of pictures and notes

Answer (score -4):

A thought about the logo:

A few music notes and a few photographs and a snippet of 35mm film stuffed into the top of a sausage-grinder-like computer or oscilloscope.

Comment: :)  Trying to think around the word "processing" ... oddly "rendering" also fits in this context ...